# Is there a better webview for Android

Tags: jquery, android, webview, sencha-touch

Is there a better webview for android? Google's own documents mention not to rely on the webview object.

But for using webkit it seems strange that it is so limited, compared to other webkit browsers used on mobile devices with comparable hardware.

This is evident in jquery mobile implementations, or similarly sencha touch implementations for web apps. The Android version suffers slowdowns, rendering issues, and a poor user experience, where other mobile devices - like an iphone - will run it fine. they both use webkit. and outside of an app, the actual android browser runs just fine.

Is there a way to really address android's problem, on a lower level? Has anyone made a more comprehensive web object for Android?

Thanks for any insight

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am afraid that both answers (Commonsware and Fuzzical Logic) are avoiding the reality.

The reality from our two-years experience of developing an HTML5 web app and later PhoneGap app (hybrid using web view) for iOS, Android and Windows Phone is:

Works great on iOS (both Safari and in WebView), works reasonable in Chrome on Android, IE on Windows 8 and IE WebView (all had issues, but can be solved) but remains **a nightmare in the Android WebView**.

The **WebView in Android was broken and is still broken** after the update to KitKat with Chromium replacing it. It simply crashes on normal HTML5 (not even getting to Javascript problems). You will find **a lot** of people in the net observing similar things.

Things like "Flash support" does have nothing to do with this - Flash this is not HTML5. Whether or not a manufacturer wants to support a certain plugin (or, in this case, a whole middleware) is up to him. I always understood Apple's decision, and in a WebView it does make even less sense.

So, the problem is an Android/Google problem, as much as the supporters of this platform want to deny it. It is particularly embarrassing of course for a company that always cried "open" and then is not able to deliver a working HTML5 browser component after so many years.

But your question was, if there is any other WebView from anybody else:

Well, we would love to hear about one. Sorry we also did not find one up to now, and the reason is probably exactly what was mentioned in the above posts: It is very difficult to implement it and it will be hardware dependent (hardware acceleration etc.). However, since Chrome works at least reasonable now (after so many years...) I wonder whether the lack of similar quality in the Chromium WebView is intentional by Google, trying to keep people away from making great web apps or hybrid apps. (Quite the opposite of what Microsoft is doing.)

Answer (score 15):

CQM,

Understand that I agree with Commonswares and nearly everything that stated in the supplied answer. However, the question seems to imply that there is an issue that you are having (either in comprehension or conception) and want to find/develop a more adequate solution for your needs.

**Addressing the question and the responses you are probably going to receive:**

I believe Commonswares **valid** criticism is due to the fact that you do not state ***why*** or ***how*** the provided platform object is unsatisfactory, nor do you state ***why*** or ***when*** you believe that Google has said that said object is unreliable. If you would like better feedback, edit your question appropriately to communicate this and you'll have fewer problems here.

Further, as explained further below, you imply that this is a problem with the Android platform (in fact, almost directly state it) and it is not. There are too many considerations in the broad scope of web browsing to be completely addressed by a simple control such as the WebView. Microsoft faced the same issue with their embedded IE COM Object back in the 90s. Its a big issue that doesn't belong to any one group.

**Addressing the implied question:**

The `WebView` object is basically a mini-browser utilizing highly flexible rendering code based on entirely different parameters from that of a dedicated browser. This includes everything from simple rendering, to even interactible (sp?) objects such as the links that such a page would employ. This process is very difficult to (for lack of a better word) to miniaturize in such a way that capability is uniform for embedding into a variety of apps that have may a different layout structure and parameters every time. Heck, such engines are hard to program uniformly even with a dedicated browsing engine, leading to a lot of the differences between the current major browsers as a whole.

As such, the `WebView` is not meant to provide the full functionality of a dedicated browser, but the most useful aspects of displaying web delivered content within an application that often does other things. This is especially true when you consider the security implications of adding Javascript functionality or client-based processing delivered from said content. Add to that, each device has the potential to have a different rendering engine or different version of the same rendering engine, much the same way that different devices have different capabilities utilizing SQLite (i.e. Foreign Key support).

As such, the WebView is provided as a solution to display web delivered content without guarantee as to its extensibility or usability *unless* you use it *purely* to view (and possibly react) trusted and standards conformant HTML code. Once you get into the actual practices of real world websites, you realize that HTML was made so flexibly specifically because each standard as adhered to at different levels by different developers. Since the primary credo of HTML is that it work (show content), despite potential ambiguities, the issue of developing a fully comprehensive app-embedded object oriented solution becomes even harder to develop.

> ... where other mobile devices - like an iphone - will run it fine

This depends on the content. Also the development philosophy for the Apple devices is entirely different from that of Android. Apple has only a handful of devices, so they can guarantee uniformity across their devices and choose which and when to add additional features. For instance, the first iPhone didn't have native support for Flash. Based on the implications of your question, I believe this fails the "comprehensive" test.

Android, in contrast, has a much wider repertoire of devices. The code for Android is adjusted and altered by the manufacturers of these devices to allow them to make more adequate supportable solutions for their specific device needs. Google cannot guarantee that any given device will keep any or all of its code the same in any way. This creates further limitations but creates other very awesome freedoms.

> ... they both use webkit.

Chrome and Safari both use webkit, as well. Many developers have been plagued by the even minute differences in the way that they both utilize it differently.

> ... outside of an app, the actual android browser runs just fine.

This is addressed above.

> Is there a way to really address android's problem, on a lower level?

Again, this is not ***android's*** problem. If you are having a specific issue with the current implementation, you are free to code a separate solution. Further, web content was made to be viewed in a browser and that is provided. The best practice is to define what you need it to do specifically. Do you need the `WebView` to view *any* web page? Or just yours? What are your issues with its current rendering? Do you require client-side scripting?

Every tool is made with particular needs in mind. This is even true of the so-called "better" listviews. Those views were made to address specific needs that might be needed by more than one developer. In the world of programming (especially OOP), there is really very little such thing as comprehensive. If there was, we wouldn't have to extend our objects in the first place. When looking at such a tool, consider what need it was specifically trying to address.

> Has anyone made a more comprehensive web object for Android?

Yes. They are normally manifested in the other dedicated browsers that you can download to your device. As to whether or not they are accessible: personally, I have no idea and am not inclined to look.

**Final Statement**

The issue you have raised was really not specific enough to provide a true solution. It also seemed to take an antagonistic stance, due to poor word choice. If your issue was not resolved by either CommonsWare's answer or my own, consider editing your question to add our more specific needs. That said, I hope both of our answers were able to provide some insight for you.

Hope this helps,

FuzzicalLogic

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised nobody mentioned [CocoonJS](https://www.ludei.com/cocoonjs/).

It has a reimplementation of the standard WebView (Webview+); a packaged Webview, so your app will run consistently across devices (albeit limited to Android 4+ and iOS 8+).

There is also an environment called Canvas+ for WebGL, but it's completely separate from WebView+. This means you'll need to overlay WebView+ on top of Canvas+ to get DOM and canvas displaying simultaneously. They don't share the same JS environment, but there is a messaging system for sending messages between the two.

CocoonJS doesn't seem like a good production-level solution because of the limited OS support, but maybe it will be in the future.

There is also [Crosswalk](https://crosswalk-project.org). It works for Android 4+ and Tizen.

Comment: Nobody mentioned it because this question was posted 3 years before your answer. Thanks for pointing it out now

Answer (score 0):

This is damn close to an off-topic, send-your-rants-elsewhere-please sort of "question".

> Is there a better webview for android?

If by "webview" you mean an embeddable Web rendering engine, probably not, as writing such engines is *hard*. You could see if one is available as an offshoot of Firefox Mobile. Or, you are welcome to make your own port of WebKit to Android, using the AOSP edition as a starting point. Note that both are likely to substantially increase the size of your app.

> Google's own documents mention not to rely on the webview object.

Citation, please.

> Has anyone made a more comprehensive web object for Android?

That would depend on one's definition of "more comprehensive web object". Notably, you neglected to provide any sort of definition for this phrase.

Comment: I'll address this information in sections over time, but people have made better listviews, better asynchronous threading, and overall problem-solving contributions to the android code base, as you already know. This is a question about the Webview object seeing if anyone has recreated it or extended it to address the real problems that the Webview object has.

Comment: @CQM: `WebView` itself sits upon a metric ton of native code, which limits our flexibility for making changes. Everything else you cited is implemented purely in Java.

Comment: @CoderSeven Maybe horrible for your skill level, but these are poignant and informative answers to someone who has worked with the platform for a while and doesn't need to have their hand held.